# How do I make a level purchase multiplier for Incremental games?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

How do I make a level purchase multiplier for Incremental games?
When a person buys any level, he has money spent and the purchase price increases by the formula:

```
        money = 1000;       
        baseCost = 100;
        multiplier = 1.09;
        lvl = 1;
        newCost;
    
    newCost = baseCost * Math.Pow(multiplier, lvl)
```

**The question is:** How do I make that the player can buy multiple levels, taking into account the rising price for each new level?
It is also important that a person cannot buy more levels than he has money.

**The multipliers will be as follows:**

1. X1 - purchase of one level.
2. X10 - purchase of 10 levels.
3. X50 - purchase of 50 levels.
4. MAX - purchase of the maximum possible number of levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm nout sure that it works correct. But it's my vision of your problem :) 
I think you should create some kind of entity for multipliers. For example Enum

```
public const double baseCost = 100.0;
public const double multiplier = 1.09;

public enum Multipliers
{
    X1 = 1,
    X10 = 10,
    X50 = 50,
    Max = -1
}

var stringLvlToBuy = "MAX"; //input value from user
double newCost = 0;
int lvl = 1;
double money = 1000;

//Parse input value To Enum or your entity for multipliers
if (!Enum.TryParse(stringLvlToBuy, out Multipliers multiplierLvl);)
{
    //Value didn't parse so you should  do something 
}

var lvlToBuy = (int) multiplierLvl;

if (multiplierLvl == Multipliers.Max)
{
    var maxLevelsToBuy = 0;
    var nextLevel = lvl + 1;
    double totalSum = baseCost * Math.Pow(multiplier, nextLevel);
    while (money > totalSum)
    {
        nextLevel++;
        maxLevelsToBuy++;
        totalSum += baseCost * Math.Pow(multiplier, nextLevel);
    }

    lvl = maxLevelsToBuy;
    money -= (totalSum - baseCost * Math.Pow(multiplier, nextLevel));
}
else
{
    var restMoney = BuyLevelsIfPossible(money, lvl, lvlToBuy);
    if (restMoney < 0.0)
    {
        //print "You don't have enough money" 
    }
    else
    {
        money = restMoney;
    }
}
  
public double BuyLevelsIfPossible(double playerMoney, int currentLevel, int lvlToBuy)
{
    var totalSum = 0.0;
    double newCost;

    for (int i = currentLevel + 1; i <= lvlToBuy; ++i)
    {
        newCost = baseCost * Math.Pow(multiplier, i);
        totalSum += newCost;
    }

    if (totalSum > playerMoney)
    {
        //do what you gonna do if money isn't enough. e.g.
        return -1;
    }

    return playerMoney - totalSum;
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting code you've got there. You were able to give me some ideas on how I could implement it. I'll go try it out!

Comment: @DmitriyBaturinets Glad I could help =)